# How to solve the warning of CAPTCHA session resuse attack

Tags: 7, captcha

I am using [captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) module (7.x, 1.0 v), When i select the image & click on upload button. Then image uploaded successfully but show this warning message also.

[image]

How to solve this issue. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug report (see answer below) which should have been reported and tracked via Captcha's issue queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in CAPTCHA module you are using. Module should be compatible with core, and file upload is one of the core functionalities of Drupal. Please report this bug to module's issue queue.

But you are not helpless. As a workaround, you can use [Multi-Step Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module. Keep CAPTCHA on first step only, and put profile photo in a second step. It will keep conflicting fields on separate forms, preventing them from interfering with each other.